# Python: reshape 2d array to 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following 2d array`abc`.

```
array([[-0.20152117, -1.44189064,  0.20784068],
       [ 0.47836196, -1.07317107, -0.17852614]])
```

I would like to transform it to a 3d array such that the result would be `res[0,:,:]` would be

Note that this `res[0]`shape is `3 x N`, with N = 10

```
array([[-0.20152117, -0.20152117, -0.20152117, ..., -0.20152117,
        -0.20152117, -0.20152117],
       [-1.44189064, -1.44189064, -1.44189064, ..., -1.44189064,
        -1.44189064, -1.44189064],
       [ 0.20784068,  0.20784068,  0.20784068, ...,  0.20784068,
         0.20784068,  0.20784068]])
```

and  `res[1]` shape is also `3xN`

```
array([[ 0.47836196,  0.47836196,  0.47836196, ...,  0.47836196,
         0.47836196,  0.47836196],
       [-1.07317107, -1.07317107, -1.07317107, ..., -1.07317107,
        -1.07317107, -1.07317107],
       [-0.17852614, -0.17852614, -0.17852614, ..., -0.17852614,
        -0.17852614, -0.17852614]])
```

How can I achieve that ?

I tried `(np.repeat(abc, 10, 0).reshape(2, 3, 10))` but this is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import numpy as np

abc = np.array([[-0.20152117, -1.44189064,  0.20784068],
              [ 0.47836196, -1.07317107, -0.17852614]])

N = 10
res = np.tile(abc.T, (N, 1, 1)).T
print(res[0])
print()
print(res[1])
```

yields

```
[[-0.20152117 -0.20152117 -0.20152117 -0.20152117 -0.20152117 -0.20152117
  -0.20152117 -0.20152117 -0.20152117 -0.20152117]
 [-1.44189064 -1.44189064 -1.44189064 -1.44189064 -1.44189064 -1.44189064
  -1.44189064 -1.44189064 -1.44189064 -1.44189064]
 [ 0.20784068  0.20784068  0.20784068  0.20784068  0.20784068  0.20784068
   0.20784068  0.20784068  0.20784068  0.20784068]]

[[ 0.47836196  0.47836196  0.47836196  0.47836196  0.47836196  0.47836196
   0.47836196  0.47836196  0.47836196  0.47836196]
 [-1.07317107 -1.07317107 -1.07317107 -1.07317107 -1.07317107 -1.07317107
  -1.07317107 -1.07317107 -1.07317107 -1.07317107]
 [-0.17852614 -0.17852614 -0.17852614 -0.17852614 -0.17852614 -0.17852614
  -0.17852614 -0.17852614 -0.17852614 -0.17852614]]
```